# Flip card effect in oracle apex

Tags: html, css, oracle, oracle-apex, apex

Is there a way to do a flip card effect in oracle apex using css? Like the following image [image]

I need a title that placed on the image and when the image is flipped I need a blank card with description (both the title and the description are selected from the database)

Answer (score 1):

If you need cards you can use cards from APEX Universal Theme, like this:

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/card-templates

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/card-regions

If you need exactly this animation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j23W8nmVKbk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-jC5PdrHeU